# Western Digital WD Red 6TB disc click of death - Spindle motor

Tags: hard-drive, sata

Unfortunately a 6TB disc just got the click of death. The motor seems to spin up fine and the read/write heads seems to move fine with the actuator. When opening I discovered something I have not seen before though. On the spindle motor there is a hole with a pin inside it. Tried googling but I could only find one image that seems to have something similar:

https://mydatarecoverylab.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/wd-re.jpg

Image from a 10TB disc does not seem to have it:

https://www.connection.com/product/western-digital-10tb-wd-red-pro-sata-6gb-s-3.5-internal-hard-drive/wd102kfbx/38030002

Is this standard or is something broken from the motor?

[image]

Old broken 2TB Western Digital Green. Looks like a normal spindle motor.

[image]

Comment: If there is a pin inside the hole, maybe it's a way to keep holes aligned during automated assembly of HDD. Or it could also be a way to manage some weight to even out vibrations.